# RavenDb LuceneQuery: How to query on List<string>

Tags: lucene, ravendb

How can I make a query on `List<string>` with Lucene? Here is my attempt, but I got an error.

```
var top10MoviesQuery = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Media, Media_Index>()
   .SetResultTransformer("MediaListTransformer")
   .SelectFields<MediaListProjection>()
   .WhereEquals(o => o.AvalibleOnServices, serviceMovie) <---- here
   .OrderByDescending(o => o.OurScore)
   .Take(10)
   .Lazily();
```

`AvalibleOnServices` is a `List<string>()` and `serviceMovie` is a `string`.

Comment: You are comparing a `List<string>` and a `string`. What do you want to achieve with that? Query documents which `AvailableOnServices` list *contains* `serviceMovie`? If so, why do you want to use Lucene for that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your purpose is to query documents which `AvailableOnServices` list contains `serviceMovie`. If that's the case you could just do something like this, you don't need Lucene for such a simple thing:

```
var top10MoviesQuery = session.Query<Media, Media_Index>()
    .Where(x => x.AvailableOnServices.Contains(serviceMovie))
    .Take(10)
    .TransformWith<MediaListTransformer, MediaListProjection>()
    .Lazily();
```

Note that:

- Here I assume that `MediaListProjection` is what `MediaListTransformer` transforms into, since you didn't mention otherwise, and
- you need to add `using Raven.Client.Linq;` to be able to invoke `TransformWith` on the results - by importing this namespace you will get an `IRavenQueryable<T>` instead of a regular `IQueryable<T>` when you call `Where`, so you will be able to invoke Raven-specific stuff such as `TransformWith` and `Lazily`.